# Human-readable short one-way hash for obscuring strings in logfiles?

Tags: string, hash

I need to do large-scale anonymisation of database log-files.

Part of this will involve obscuring various field names (strings), as well as IP addresses.

**1. Field Names**

For example, we might have the string `BusinessLogic.Categorisation.ExternalDeals`. In the anonymised version, we would want it to be something like `Jerrycan.Doorway.Fodmap` (or something gibberish, but still "pronounceable")

The purpose is simply to obscure the original strings - however, we *still* want to be able to matchup occurrence of those strings across different logfiles.

The requirements of the hash are:

- Repeatable - that is, the same inputs passed in each time would always produce the same outputs. We need to be able to match-up fields between different logfiles (all we're trying to prevent is somebody deriving the original string).
- One-way - there is no way of reversing the outputs to product the inputs.
- Low chance of collision - it will mess up our analysis if two fields are mapped to the same output.
- Human readable (or pronounceable) - somebody scanning through logfiles by hand should be able to make out fields, and visually match them up. Or if need be, read them over the phone.
- Short strings - I do understand there's a tradeoff between this and available entropy, however, ideally a string like `HumanReadable` should map to something like `LizzyNasbeth`.

I had a look around, and I found https://github.com/zacharyvoase/humanhash (output hash is a bit longer than what I want) and https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1751 (not really "pronouceable" - ideally, we'd want something that looks like a English-language human word, but isn't actually - and, once again, a bit long).

**What algorithms or approaches are there to this problem? Or any libraries or implementations you could recommend?**

**2. IP Addresses**

For the IP addresses, we need a way to mask them (i.e. not possible for an outside observer to derive the original IP address), but still have it be repeatable across different logfiles (i.e. the same input always produces the same output).

Ideally, the output would still "look" like an IP address. For example, maybe 192.168.1.55 would map to 33.41.22.44 (or we can use alphabetical codes as well, if that's easier).

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: Could you just generate a "gibberish word" database and a "gibberish IP" database, then map your words /IP addresses that require substitution to a random "gibberish" entry?  Your lookups would be repeatable, and only reversible to to those that have the database.  Is that sufficient to meet your criteria?

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to not rely on a lookup table, but have it pass through a one-way hash. (We'd need to distribute the code to do the anonymisation to a few places, and also the lookup table to several other places who had to do the analysis - unfortunately, that's not going to fly well - whereas if it's just a hash function we can share with everybody, they won't object).

Comment: I think the crux of your problem is that the point of any hash function is for the output to be unpredictable, yet you're wanting to be able to predict the output (to be "human readable").  If there's a solution for you, I don't think it'll involve hashing.

Comment: You'll need a very context-sensitive tokenizer/parser, just to avoid that "Progname: BusinessLogic.Categorisation.ExternalDeals: symbol not found" is translated into "Jesus: Apple.Peach.BananaShot: horse eye roger"

Comment: I'm concerned that the "not reversible" part of this will be difficult. If there's a reasonable space of possible inputs, then someone could just run a bunch of plausible inputs through the system to figure out what they map to. At that point, they could then reverse your hiding system by just looking at the generated output and consulting a lookup table to recover the input. What level of security are you looking for here?

Comment: It's for obscuring things like field names and company names - i.e. they're providing DB query logfiles  an external vendor for analysis. It's not things like credit cards or emails addresses (actual DB results will be md5-ed) - but they're just a little paranoid about any specific info being linked to them. Also, there's a fairly large input space - i.e. every possible company name in the world =), or every database field name you can come up with, so I'm not so concerned about dictionary attacks. Something that can reasonably product still-readable obfuscated logfiles will work.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [codenamize](https://github.com/jjmontesl/codenamize) :

```
$ codenamize BusinessLogic -j "" -c
AbsorbedUpper
```

You can use this from command line or as a Python library.

*(Disclaimer, I wrote it).*

Answer (score 1):

I was discussing with a colleague, and he suggested one approach.

1. Take the field name - and pass it through a standard one-way hash (e.g. MD5).
2. Use the resulting digest as a index to map to a dictionary of English words (e.g. using mod).

That solves the issue of it always being repeatable - the same word hashed each time will always map to the same English word (assuming your dictionary list does not change).

If individuals companies were worried about dictionary attacks (i.e. the field name "firstname" would always map to say "Paris"), then we could also use a company-specific keyfile to salt the hash. This means that it would be repeatable for anonymised logfiles from them (i.e. "firstname" might always map to "Toulouse" for them), but it would not be the same as for other companies who use other keyfiles.

I'm still very keen to see what other people can suggest, or whether they might have any thoughts on the above.